# How could I add life paths to Rogue Trader?

Tags: character-creation, rogue-trader, life-paths

My friend is starting up a Rogue Trader game soon, but it was a close call between that and Traveller Char gen...that's right, not the game but just the character generation. Last time I played character generation for Traveller that was far more interesting than the actual game.

I've only played Dark Heresy and I assume it has the same sort of character generation. How easy would it be to add life paths to Rogue Trader? Has it been done before/does it already feature lifepaths? And if not where should I start?

Comment: related, but not completely covering my question here: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12901/how-can-i-introduce-life-paths-to-character-generation?rq=1

Comment: Hmm... Rogue Trader already includes a kind of life path character creation, so I'm not sure what about the existing system you want to alter: Each character is defined by answering six questions about what the character was doing during a particular stage of life, with the answer to each question constraining options available for the next. Is this too restrictive? Do you want more options? Do you want to split each stage up into multiple questions? Do you want more detail about what the questions contain? Do you want more random rolls, Traveller-style?

Comment: To be honest, @GMJoe I haven't a copy of Rogue trader, but I assumed it was fairly similar to Dark Heresy. I'll edit the question later today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be too hard to generate a slightly more in-depth lifepath system for Rogue Trader if what you're looking for is a history of events for the character prior to their control by yourself.

I can't find any additional lifepath systems for Rogue Trader around, but a start could be using the [lifepath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberpunk_2020) generation system from Cyberpunk; there is an online version of [the generator here](http://www.moosh.net/cp2020/lifepath-form.html).

This is a very simple but generic lifepath generator, so it's easily adaptable.
It gives you a year-on-year list of events for the character that you can then be scripted out into something more detailed for the world system that you're using. The styles of cyberpunk and rogue trader (dark futures) aren't a million miles apart so it shouldn't be too hard.

Plus it's online and can be generated in seconds. ;)